# When to use "was coming" or "would come"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, non-native-english

You went to a party with your friends, you arrived by car and your friend arrived by bus. It was very late at the end of the party and you were driving your friend home.
He said:

> It was really kind of you to drive me home.

You should answer:

> Oh, don't mention it. I **was coming** past your house anyway

or

> Oh, don't mention it. I **would come** past your house anyway

Which one is correct here?
I have googled and read some references, but it's different from my situation

Comment: I think you've reversed *coming* and *going* here.

Comment: Both are possible.  "It was my plan to drive past your house anyway" or "In the normal course of events I would pass your house" - different ways of expressing the same idea.

Comment: *I go this way anyway.*

Comment: If the exchange happened *before* the ride: "I would go past your house anyway". If *after* the ride: "I was coming past your house anyway."

Comment: Can you explain it from a grammatical perspective? Thanks

Comment: There is no grammar issue to explain. You can use different verbs to say you were driving, riding, going, passing, traveling, routing, swinging by, heading.